# Postgres sequencing composite key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table_a with column product_id, store_id, x.

I want to

```
create table_b as
select store_id, product_id, sequence_number
from table_a
```

sequence_number is auto generated number that is supposed to look like this:

```
store_id            |   product_id              |   sequence_number
1                   |   1                       |   1
1                   |   1                       |   2
1                   |   1                       |   3
1                   |   2                       |   1
1                   |   2                       |   2
2                   |   1                       |   1
2                   |   1                       |   2
```

Is it possible to do this with sql query?

Comment: You are looking for `row_number()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
create table_b as
    select store_id, product_id,
           row_number() over (partition by store_id, product_id
                              order by NULL
                             ) as sequence_number
    from table_a;
```

Comment: Thanks! But what's the meaning of order by NULL?

Comment: @YukaFujisaku . . . It is equivalent to leaving out the `order by` clause.  However, I think leaving it out is a bit confusing, because most databases require it.